# How to enable qiskit logging? Where is the log file?

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to debug a qiskit circuit that won't "unroll." Looking at the source code, there are a log of logging calls but they aren't enabled. How can I enable logging in qiskit? Where is the log written?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some example code of the circuit you're working with and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit uses standard Python logging which means all the logging calls you see in the source code go to Python's built-in logging infrastructure and how those get written out or displayed is configurable. The details on how to use it are documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

By default only log messages at the `WARNING` level or above will be displayed. If you'd like to see more of the logging messages you can run something like:

```python
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")
```

and that will print all the log messages to your console. If you'd like to write
the log messages to a file you can run this instead:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG", filename="output.log")
```

Nte you can only call `basicConfig` once as it sets the handler on the root logger and it won't override that by default, unless you set the argument `force=True`.

More details on the specifics of this around Qiskit's transpiler are documented here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/04_transpiler_passes_and_passmanager.html#Transpiler-Logging